# Magic Eden API issue instruction 'buy'

Tags: python-3.x, solana

I'm trying to create a offers bot using the ME public API, but when I try to submit a buy(bid) it gives status 200, and the buffers that should appear, but my wallet didn't send any `tx`, and I can't see the offer done in my profile.

This is my code:

```
import requests

url = "https://api-mainnet.magiceden.dev/v2/instructions/buy?buyer='MYWALLET'&auctionHouseAddress=E8cU1WiRWjanGxmn96ewBgk9vPTcL6AEZ1t6F6fkgUWe&tokenMint=4StP8k8MFsSug39xF4Y4CK3tS6fPxA3qsTTXAUFDHqv5&price=0.13"

headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "authorization": "Bearer 'PRIVATE KEY'"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```